# Laravel and Redis: session driver 'array'

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

So I have Laravel project and Redis. `SESSION_DRIVER` in my project .env file is currently set to `file`. I want to change it to `array`, but when I do so, the project stops working properly: I get logged off, and when I log in, I get redirected back to login page, being logged off again and again. What actions should I take to fix this and make my project work correctly with `array` session driver?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to set SESSION_DRIVER to "redis" instead? The array driver doesn't persist across requests, so isn't ever going to keep you logged in.

Comment: the array driver is for testing only. change that to redis if u are not testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read up on the [session documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session). It specifically states that when using the `array` driver:

> array - sessions are stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.

Since the session does not persist, you will not be able to log in. Basically, the `array` session driver is solely for testing purposes.